# Silverlight3: What to use: WebClient or database with RIA

Tags: database, silverlight-3.0, webclient

I'm asking for the advice. I'm working at the Silverlight 3 application and now I should select the mean how to save the information and get it. I could save the necessary info in files (from 1 to 300K size) or I could save them in database. If I would use WebClient for accessing to separate file there's very low loading of the server. If I get data from database the server would load much more I think and the code on the server too.

Please correct me if I'm not right.
I'm looking forward to hearing from you!
Thanks

Comment: What type of data are you trying to store? What are these files?

Answer (score 1):

there are additional considerations if you use a file that is localized to the users machine.  If you wish to save data w/o any user intervention then you are limited to using Isolated Storage, which has constraints on the size of your data.  Otherwise, you have to ask the user for information on where to save/load the file.  This is due to the security model used by silverlight.

i am thinking that a Database and the RIA framework might be the way to go.

just my 2¢

Comment: I'm not going to allow user save files locally. Even if so, the main problem is how to get data from the server.
Thanks anyway

Comment: But yes, the considerations you said about are important for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving and loading the entire file at a time, then it might be okay to use a WebClient. This might take a little coding to handle errors that may result in incomplete saves.

If you're serializing some objects or xml data and storing that in a file, then you should probably be using a database instead.

Edit: It can be a pain to get WebClient or HttpWebRequest working correctly with GET/POST, but WCF can also be a pain to configure if you haven't done it before. WCF is probably better style, and you'll want to use a binary binding and send the file across as a byte[].